# how to enable and configure USB OTG for device mode on iMX31 Litekit?

Tags: imx31, arm, usb

I need to configure USB OTG on iMX31 for device mode. We need a raw channel between the host and target and usb seems to be the best suited. However I haven't been able to correctly configure the OTG controller. I dont know what I am missing. I have performed the steps mentioned in section 32.14.1 of iMX31 Reference Manual. I have also configured PORTSC1 register for ULPI.

Can any one help me out here? any poineters/code/any thing that can help me is welcome.

Comment: you might rather post this question on the Freescale forum(may be you already have).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had answered you on stackoverflow: don't know if you had read this answer: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583472/how-to-enable-and-configure-usb-otg-for-device-mode-on-imx31-litekit/3600203#3600203)